# Strange behaviour when reading from stdin in R

Tags: r, stdin

I am trying to understand what happens when reading from `STDIN` when executing an Rscript.

First I have a file with the data I want to read into R:

```
root@CentOS64 testscripts # cat rdata
5 7
```

This is my first Rscript,

```
a <- scan(file="stdin", what=integer(0), n=1);
b <- scan(file="stdin", what=integer(0), n=1);
```

Which results in this behaviour:

```
root@CentOS64 testscripts # Rscript ../rscripts/ttest.r < rdata
Read 1 item
Read 0 items
root@CentOS64 testscripts # cat rdata | Rscript ../rscripts/ttest.r
Read 1 item
Read 0 items
```

At this point I am already confused, as to why only one value is read. I have been trying to find more information about the `scan` function but I can't find anything that would explain this.

If I change the Rscript to the following,

```
sin <- file("/dev/stdin");
a <- scan(sin, what=integer(0), n=1);
b <- scan(sin, what=integer(0), n=1);
```

I get this result instead:

```
root@CentOS64 testscripts # Rscript ../rscripts/ttest.r < rdata
Read 1 item
Read 1 item
root@CentOS64 testscripts # cat rdata | Rscript ../rscripts/ttest.r
Read 0 items
Read 0 items
```

This makes me even more confused as to me the results should be equivalent. Lastly, if I try this command:

```
root@CentOS64 testscripts # cat rdata > tmp; Rscript ../rscripts/ttest.r < tmp
Read 1 item
Read 1 item
```

I get the intended behavour. Can someone please explain to me what is going on? Why can't R read data form a pipe in a streaming fashion?

Comment: Try using `stdin()` to point to `stdin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `scan` with `"stdin"` as the input, it reads the *whole* stdin at once, even if you just restricted it to one character. The second time you call it, there is nothing left, so it returns nothing.

If you want to read stdin "one at a time", you can use file connections with the "read" mode set. If you make your `ttest.r` script this:

```
con=file("stdin", "r")
scan(file=con, what=integer(0), n=1)
scan(file=con, what=integer(0), n=1)
```

And then you call from your shell:

```
Rscript ttest.r < rdata
# Read 1 item
# [1] 5
# Read 1 item
# [1] 7
```

---

I am a bit confused as to why you wouldn't get the same thing I tried piping the other way:

```
cat rdata | Rscript ttest.r
# Read 1 item
# [1] 5
# Read 1 item
# [1] 7
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunaly I get the same problem as I descibed in my post. If I run the command `cat rdata | Rscript ../rscripts/ttest.r` it still reads 0 items.

Comment: If you open `R` interactively, does running `con=file("rdata","r")`, and then the two `scan` commands work?

Comment: No, I get the following output: `Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
      scan() expected 'an integer', got 'scan(file=con,'`

Comment: Hi, I screwed up when I tried your code the first time. I tried it again and this time it worked. I guess I forgot to save or something. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you like the answer, you can click the check box next to the answer.